# Correct way to flex two rows?

Tags: flexbox, angular-material

I'm really struggeling to learn angular material layouts. I made a simple pen to illustrate what I'm trying to do, I'm confused about two things:

1. How do I use layout-fill? When i put in on the container div for my rows the text overflows in the boxes, why? (my goal is to take up the whole space under the two boxes)
2. I'm trying to flex the second row (where box 3 is) to be 1/3 of the page. I put `flex="33"` on the row div but it looks like it makes the row 2/3 of the screen. when I set the flex value to 66 its looks even funnier...

Here is the pen: http://codepen.io/organismen/pen/jAmzxx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/rLmKdm?editors=1100)

I've stripped out a lot of the markup so it's easier to see what's going on. You need to place the `layout-fill` upper most so that your content fills all the space. Then you have to add `flex='66'` to the first row (and just `flex` for the second row) followed by `flex` (='100', by default) for each child.

Markup

```
<body>
  <div layout="column" flex layout-fill>
    <md-card>
      <md-card-content>
        This pen shows how angular materials works across different browsers
      </md-card-content>
    </md-card>

    <div layout="row" layout-xs="column" flex>
      <div layout="column" flex="66" flex-xs="100">
        <md-card class="box-1" flex>
          <md-card-content>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta iure dignissimos iste ea nisi quidem officia perspiciatis eos, quod ratione distinctio deleniti porro unde quo sequi ut debitis doloremque. Aperiam?
      </md-card-content>
        </md-card>

        <md-card class="box-2" flex>
          <md-card-content>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta iure dignissimos iste ea nisi quidem officia perspiciatis eos, quod ratione distinctio deleniti porro unde quo sequi ut debitis doloremque. Aperiam?
          </md-card-content>
        </md-card>
      </div>

      <div layout="column" flex="33" flex-xs="33">
        <md-card class="box-3" flex>
          <md-card-content>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta iure dignissimos iste ea nisi quidem officia perspiciatis eos, quod ratione distinctio deleniti porro unde quo sequi ut debitis doloremque. Aperiam?
          </md-card-content>
        </md-card>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.box-1, .box-2, .box-3 {
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

[Documentation for layout-fill](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/options)

[Documentation for flex](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/children)

Comment: Thanks for your response! It seems to work but one of my goals in my pen was to have responsive design where the boxes would stackup (column) if the screen size is too small.

Also it seems like the text overflows in you pen like it does in my pen, I guess it has to do with the layout-fill, can we fix this?

Comment: My guess is that in the "row div" I must add something like `<div layout="column" layout-gt-sm="row">` but then my flex values messes up ?

Comment: @organismen I should be able to fix the responsive part but not until Sunday.

Comment: @organismen See the updated answer and CodePen. `layout-xs` and `flex-xs` is used to define the small screen layout. CSS is used to make sure the text doesn't overflow.

Comment: Thanks alot! Just a thought, lets say I wanted the rows to collapse > sm, wouldn't it be more logical to like I wrote in my previous comment: `<div layout="column" layout-gt-sm="row"`. (so kinda like the opposite way around)  When I try this my results are different from your solution and I would like to understand why?

Comment: @organismen That's quite tricky actually. I tried this morning but could not get it to work. I'll have another go tomorrow.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that I'm not the only one